# PyTorch Model's gradients are converging to zero

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm currently working on a personal implementation of the Transformer architecture. The code I've written as [here](https://github.com/seanswyi/transformer-implementation).

The problem that I'm facing is that I believe my model isn't training properly and I'm not sure what kind of measures I should take to fix that. I've come to this conclusion after using Weights & Biases to visualize the model's gradient histograms and they look something like this:

[image]

The gradients seem to quickly converge to zero. There is a portion of code that contains a feedforward neural network that uses ReLU activation, and I changed this to Leaky ReLU under the suspicion that dying ReLU's may be the problem. However, using Leaky ReLU's doesn't help and just prolongs the zero-convergence.

Any feedback on what else I may try is appreciated.

Comment: What do the losses look like? Do you have evidence from them that the model isn't training properly?

Comment: Loss looks something like this: https://imgur.com/a/anrnZaz The loss doesn't really decrease from here, and the this picture combined with the weights not really moving tells me the model isn't training properly. More evidence is that when I evaluate the "trained" model, the BLEU score is 0, which also shouldn't be happening.